# EVOLUTION OF MAN QUESTION

Tags: human-evolution

I have a few questions concerning man's origins 
.
Man has 10  vital Organs and support systems. yes or no? Man needs all 10 of his vital Organs or he dies. yes or no?
.
Either those 10 vital organs evolved together all at once, or they evolved separately.. yes or no?
.
If they "Evolved" Separately they must have had an order of evolution. yes or no?

Can anyone provide a plausible order of evolution of vital organs from microbe to microbiologist? (TOE)

Stomach Skin Heart Lungs Brain Upper Intestine Liver Lower 
.
Intestine Pancreas Kidneys

which one(s) could have been the first, second, third etc..?

If UCA for all flora and fauna (Evolution) were to somehow be true, and If we slowly go back in time, Our "Ancestor(s)" would, at some point, have 9 Interdependent vital organs, then 8, then 7, then 6 5 4 3 2... Yes? or no?

A Microbe has ZERO interdependent interlocked VITAL Organs and their support systems. A Microbiologist has TEN interdependent. interlocked. VITAL Organs and their support systems.  Yes? or No?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71641/discussion-on-question-by-user39485-evolution-of-man-question).

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You have a fundamental misunderstanding of evolution by natural selection.
2. You appear to be wanting to pick a fight. Its obvious no answer that refutes creationism would satisfy you.

In fact your issues have been addressed over 150 years ago in Darwin's Origins. Many wonderful books exist today expanding upon it.

I suggest you pick up a text, watch a video, or read an article on the fundamentals of evolutionary theory. Google is a good place to start.

Comment: I agree, but this is not an answer, it is a comment. The poster will not take your advice and will be happy that you have written something he can argue with. There is a golden rule here: "Don't feed the trolls".

Comment: Good point David.. Instead of trying to answer the question, he just insults me (ANYONE can do that) and simply DODGES the question..  So should I not ask questions?  If my 1question cant be answered, wouldnt it be more honest to just say so and admit that the Methodological Microbes to Microbiologist Myth is merely q Science Fiction Tale about "Long ago and far away" that people believe in ONLY because of it's IMPLICATIONS?

Comment: You can ask questions, of course! That is what this site is for. However, it is *not* a debate forum. If you actually want to understand something, and have a question about it then ask. If you want to try and persuade people about creationism, then I would say - do you really think that will work?

Comment: So It appears painfully obvious that the answer to my question is a resounding NO!

Comment: MamaTank 
"1.You have a fundamental misunderstanding of evolution by natural selection." 


2.You appear to be wanting to pick a fight. Its obvious no answer that refutes creationism would satisfy you.


In fact your issues have been addressed over 150 years ago in Darwin's Origins. Many wonderful books exist today expanding upon it.

I suggest you pick up a text, watch a video, or read an article on the fundamentals of evolutionary theory. Google is a good place to start.

Comment: MamaTank
"1.You have a fundamental misunderstanding of evolution by natural selection." .....  That is merely a baseless assertion.. you don't know me, you don't know what I do or do not know, This is what is called an "Ad Hom" logical fallacy and is Irrelevant to my question which is "Can anyone provide a plausible order of the 10 Vital Organs from microbe to microbiologist"?  Yes or No.. If the answer is Yes, please provide the order  1 through 10  Thank you

Comment: MamaTank  "2.You appear to be wanting to pick a fight. Its obvious no answer that refutes creationism would satisfy you."    Wrong.. I only want the truth.. If Evolution is true, I want to know it.. Presenting a plausible order (1-10) of Vital Organs from microbe to microbiologist would clearly demonstrate that Creationism is not the only Valid explanation for Man's origins..

Comment: MamaTank  "In fact your issues have been addressed over 150 years ago in Darwin's Origins. Many wonderful books exist today expanding upon it." Wrong again..If you believe this, you did not understand the question at all because if you did, you would surely already know that my question has NOT been addressed anywhere in ANY of those books. If it was, I surely would have had it shown to me by someone by now remember we need to see an Order 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10..   Thanks anyway, but clearly you cannot answer my question or know anyone who can..

Comment: MamaTank  "Many wonderful books exist today expanding upon it. I suggest you pick up a text, watch a video, or read an article on the fundamentals of evolutionary theory. Google is a good place to start." Sorry, been there and done that.. Just because people ask questions doesn't mean that they are low IQ or Ignorant or haven't studied the topic  I am quite certain I know quite a bit more about the topic of Origins then anyone that you know.. I only asked the question to get people to think instead of simply parroting the propaganda that they have been brainwashed into believing.. Good Luck JT